I am confused how to connect api to wordpress template (2)
I am building a website using WordPress and want to display data fetched from an API developed with Express.js. I’ve written code to fetch data from the database using an Express.js API and display it via WordPress REST API, but the data is not appearing on the website.
Here are the details of my setup:
Express.js API is running on http://localhost:3456/api/items:
The GET /api/items endpoint returns a list of items.
The POST /api/items endpoint adds new items.
WordPress REST API is used to fetch data from Express.js and display it in the theme.
Code Used in WordPress:
// Add WordPress REST API to connect with Express.js API
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('vehica/v1', '/items', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'vehica_get_items',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ]);
});

function vehica_get_items(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $api_url = 'http://localhost:3456/api/items';
    $response = wp_remote_get($api_url);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return new WP_Error('api_error', 'Failed to fetch items from API', ['status' => 500]);
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    return rest_ensure_response(json_decode($body, true));
}

Problem:
Data fetched from the API is not showing on the website, even though I’ve tried fetching it using PHP and JavaScript.
No clear error messages appear in the browser console or logs.
Steps I’ve Taken:
Verified the API works correctly using Postman.
Checked if vehica_get_items is being called via the REST API at http://example.com/wp-json/vehica/v1/items.
Added CORS headers in the Express.js API to ensure requests are allowed.
Checked the WordPress and API server error logs.
Questions:
What might be wrong with my setup?
How can I ensure that data from the API displays correctly on the website?
get a solution to the problem I have

Just checking, but, the wordpress you are building is in your machine as the expressjs app, and the $body of the method vehica_get_items  is empty after the request ? has the $response an error message ?

it's been several times but still the same

That doesn't answer my question. Is your wordpress on a server, or in your computer like the expressjs app ? And do a var_dump($response), and add it to the question content.

I have tried it. First for server and web I run it on the same device. Second for var_dump($response) the result is like this. result

vehica_get_items  is empty after the request ? yes

I want the php response, to know the error, not the console log from the browser. When you do a var_dump, php just throws the object as text. And the function could be empty by many reasons. Also, try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

I can't find where to see the error that occurred, I've tried searching from hosting but I can't find it.

"Added CORS headers in the Express.js API to ensure requests are allowed." - you are making the request from the server side, so CORS restrictions don't apply here in the first place. "Data fetched from the API is not showing on the website" - and where did you actually try to show it ...? So far, you have shown us how you set up your Rest API endpoint, and confirmed it works via postman. But where is the part where you make your page actually request that API endpoint, and do anything with the result ...?

To get your data from your API to your WordPress server and from there to your user’s browser, you need JavaScript in the page to make an AJAX or fetch request to the REST code you showed us. You need to do a GET request to
/wp-json/vehica/v1/items

in that Javascript, then use that Javascript to display the data that comes back to the user. You didn’t show that code in your question. Do you have it?
Many people who implement this sort of remote API access use a custom shortcode to get the API data visible to an end user. At least as a prototype to get things working.
You can add a custom block for the same purpose that uses your REST api if need be.
Pro tip. Cache the result of hitting the API in a transient with a timeout of a few minutes to avoid hammering your API if your traffic scales up.
